# Exchange calendar resource sharing externally

Tags: office-365, calendar, exchange-server

We are about to move into a shared building where we will be required to share meeting rooms with a few other small companies.

We currently use exchange on a small business server but will be moving to office365 for email soon. Is there any way to share a calendar resource with external users?

Comment: Serverfault is for questions about systems you manage, not hosted services.  I believe using resources externally is possible with a full version of Exchange, I have no ideal what office365 provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at **Internet Calendar Sharing**. It sounds like what you want, but give [Exchange 2010 SP1 and Exchange Online (Office 365) Calendaring FAQ](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2011/02/16/exchange-2010-sp1-and-exchange-online-office-365-calendaring-faq.aspx) a read over (from the Exchange team blog) and see if it is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. searching is all about having the right keywords, and sometimes you just don't have them.